# Could not find or load main class StanfordCoreNlpDemo.class while compiling StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java

Tags: java, compilation, nlp

Error while compiling..Could not find or load main class StanfordCoreNlpDemo.class while compiling StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java..how do you solve

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any details about how you compile your code, but it looks like you're using **java** instead of **javac**.

**java** is a command to start an already compiled app.

**javac** is a command to compile your source code (.java) to bytecode (.class).

Please, see the documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html
or 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html